# Spring Data : issue with OneToMany, child not saved properly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data

I am having trouble dealing with `@OneToMany` relationship.

Here is my code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "type_mouvement")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class TypeMouvement implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="typeMouvement", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<CompteTypeMouvement> comptes;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "type_mouvement_comptes")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class CompteTypeMouvement implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String numCompte;

    @ManyToOne
    private TypeMouvement typeMouvement;
...
}
```

How I use these entities :

```
TypeMouvement typeMouvementFromDB = typeMouvementRepository.findOne(new Long(1));
CompteTypeMouvement compte = new CompteTypeMouvement();
compte.setNumCompte("123");
compte.setTypeMouvement(typeMouvementFromDB);
typeMouvementFromDB.getComptes().add(compte);
typeMouvementRepository.save(typeMouvementFromDB);
```

The result I get :

[image]

I thought I would get :

[image]

Why are the properties of `CompteTypeMouvement` not filled when I save `TypeMouvement`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to invoke save passing an already existing entity:

```
TypeMouvement typeMouvementFromDB = typeMouvementRepository.findOne(new Long(1));
typeMouvementRepository.save(typeMouvementFromDB);
```

The relationship has a persist cascade type only though:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="typeMouvement", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<CompteTypeMouvement> comptes;
```

The save impl is a follows (spring-data-jpa-1.11.3):

```
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Which means that a `merge` instead of a `persist` will be invoked.

This if you add `merge` to cascade it should work:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="typeMouvement", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
  cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private List<CompteTypeMouvement> comptes;
```

Comment: If he is saving a TypeMouvement  then won't he need to add the cascade on the `@ManyToOne`?

Comment: If he was saving CompteTypeMouvement then yes.. and in that case he would only need PERSIST cascade. But that is not the situation

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand